# I'm trying to download a subttle from hotstar and when I access the link it gives me Access Denied

Tags: m3u8

hotstar recently put subbtiles on their videos and I would like to download but I don't know if it's possible.
I found the link through google console-network...

```
https://staragvod3-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/plus/naka/408/1000206610_,180,400,800,1300,2000,3000,4500,_STAR.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8?subtitle_identifier=1000206610~exp=1520200210~acl=/*~hmac=f9cb522cef3d6e60d441df30a6cdd6e79dd29701b4b52cbea332462b4281ebc9
```

when I try to access it it gives me Access Denied, any way to bypass that and download the file ?

someone also uploaded a tutorial and on his tutorial was this link :
https://staragvod3-vh.akamaihd.net/i/videos/worldwide/movies/hindi/1770015483_1/177001...+TyfgFKThgBQ==

which works and downloads the file but mine not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually after I posted this my mind worked :)
I needed a vpn to bypass the website then I could access that.